# Check whether file exists in server with partial name

Tags: file, search, partial

I want to search for a file, say with name having the date time stamp (**DDMMYYYYhhmmss**)(14122017143339). But in the server possibilities are there that the filename which I am expecting can be like either (14122017143337 OR 14122017143338 OR 14122017143339 OR 14122017143340) as there is a minute change in the seconds. 
Now, I am trying to search for the file with only a portion of its name say like (**DDMMYYYYhhmm**)only uptil the minute. Meaning the file which i am expecting should contain the string (141220171433) in its name.

Can someone help on how can we achieve this Using Java?

**Note - Am using Selenium for my coding purposes.**

Comment: If you only search till 'DDMMYYYYhhmm', it will result in many files created in that particular minute 'mm'.

Answer (score 0):

Below code in in Java and will find all files in a folder. you can search for required file name to match

```
File[] allFiles = new File("FOlder path").listFiles();
for (File f : allFiles)
{
        if (f.isFile())
        {
            if(file.getName().contains("DDMMYYYYhhmm"))
            {
                System.out.println("true and file found");
                  // do something here
            }
        }
    }
```